# Remove incremental number from List and decrement following

Tags: list, flutter, algorithm, dart

*First of all this is a common question not related to the Dart
language, but because I need it for Dart, I tagged it like so.*

I have a List of objects which contain an incremental number

```dart
List<MyObject> myObjectList = [
  MyObject(1),
  MyObject(2),
  ...
  MyObject(10),
];

class MyObject {
  int order;

  MyObject(this.order);
}
```

I now want to remove an item from the List and the following order numbers to decrease. So lets say I remove item with order number 5, the ones with 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 should decrement by one, resulting in a List like:

```dart
List<MyObject> myObjectList = [
  MyObject(1),
  MyObject(2),
  ...
  MyObject(9),
];
```

This can easily be done with a for-loop checking the items number:

```dart
var removedOrder = 5;

for (var item in myObjectList){
  if (item.order > removedOrder) {
    item.order -= 1;
  }
}
```

This is really simple to understand and should work, but honestly, simple is boring and ugly.
Is there a way to achieve the desired result without the need to write a for loop?
Also what are your suggestions to optimize that logical part?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be: When you delete and item from the list on position lets say 5, then you can take the last item in the list and change its value to 5. This removes the need to run through all the items and decreasing its values.

Comment: This would be a possible solution for other scenarios, but in my case I want to maintain the order

Comment: If your class MyObject stored additional attributes (e.g. 'name' and so on) and you want your list to remain in the same order (e.g. MyObject(10, 'john') that was on last possition) and last object to remain on the last postion, i dont think there is other way to loop through the objects in a the array and decrease there value. One optiomazition that comes to mind when i see the code is that you dont need to actually loop through all the list, but only through the objects in the list after the item that has been removed. For ( a = removedIndex; a <= list.length; a++) {}